# Does Windows 8 replace Daemon tools?

Tags: gaming

I have windows 8 and don't have daemon tools and didn't know if windows 8 could replace daemon tools. Does it?

Comment: This question is pretty vague and hard to answer - Daemon Tools performs several functions, which did you mean?  Also, why did you tag this "gaming"?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 can mount ISOs natively. That is about all, but for any legitimate purposes this suffices quite fine and there is no longer a need for daemon tools/virtual clone drive/etc.

Comment: +1 I didn't know Win 8 mounted ISO formats natively. This seems to be more inline with what he was asking for.

Comment: @JoshCampbell - Except `Daemon Tools` does a bunch of other stuff in addition to the major feature of virtual disk drives.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a Windows 8 compatible version of Daemon tools here. [Daemon Tools lite](http://astroddl.com/daemon+tools+lite+free+download+windows+8+64+bit.html)